# Inserting listbox values with multi select into table

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I've been on this issue for quite some time. I've gotten some answers be none the give me completely what i'm looking for. I have a multiselectable table and would like to add whatever selected into one of my tables in my access database. Now, I'd like this to be reverseable meaning that when I pull the data back into the form ie a search function, the user will see his/her perviouly selected data.

Here's my code i'm currently trying to different types of solutions.

```
    Private Sub Command499_Click()
'    Set RstRecSet = Nothing
'    Set db = CurrentDb
'    Dim dateDay As String
'    Dim dateWeek As String
'    MsgBox (lstDateDay.Value)
'    ''dateWeek = lstDateWeek.Value
'
'    db.Execute " INSERT INTO tblContacts (DateDay, DateWeek)Values" & "('" & dateDay & "', '" & dateWeek & "');"
'    db.Close
'
'Private Sub Command19_Click()
   Dim db As Database
   Dim rs As Recordset

   Set db = CurrentDb()
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblContacts")
   For Each itm In lstDateWeek.ItemsSelected
        rs.AddNew
        rs!dateWeek = lstDateWeek.ItemData(itm)
        rs!dateDay = itm
        rs.Update
  Next
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you mean MultiSelect ListBox - not Table? The following is an example of how you can remember items selected, clear them, then turn on the 'Selected' property in a listbox.

I have a listbox on a form, I MultiSelect some combination, then I click button for 'cmdClear'. It 'remembers' items selected and clears the list selections.  Later, I click button 'cmdMark' and it selects the entries from before. I assume you may requery the listbox after inserting records? You will need to modify the code to suit your needs (i.e. save a key value instead of a position).

```
Dim iListBox(100)   As Integer
Dim iListCount      As Integer

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
Dim i       As Integer
Dim varItem As Variant
    For i = 0 To 100
        iListBox(i) = 0
    Next i
     For i = 0 To region_lst.ListCount - 1
        If region_lst.Selected(i) Then
            iListBox(i) = 1
            region_lst.Selected(i) = False
        End If
     Next i
End Sub

Private Sub cmdMark_Click()
Dim i           As Integer
Dim varItem     As Variant
    For i = 0 To region_lst.ListCount - 1
        If iListBox(i) = 1 Then
            region_lst.Selected(i) = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Wyane, Thanks for the response! If I understand your code correctly you're running through a listbox and marking the recored number with 1(true, data is selected) or 0(false, no data is selected). If I'm correct I could rework this code to make a bool in my table however this would require me to add a feild for every listbox item. I'd like to avoid this due to the fact that it might clog my table and add lots of unnessary feilds.

Comment: To clearify, I'm trying to add data from my multi selectable listbox into a table. If all possible i'd like to avoid making a feild in my table for every listbox item. let me know if this is possible or would make things way more complicated than needed. Thanks again, Connor.

Comment: No, I'm not using a field in a table. I am looping thru a listbox and taking an inventory of which entries were selected (i.e. 1, 3, 5, 12) based on POSITION -- NOT VALUE (that will be important if you refresh the lsitbox). Later, I go back to the listbox and and mark the same rows that were originally selected -- NOT BY VALUE, but by POSITION. I believe in your case, you need to save the 'key' value. Again, do you mean you have a 'MultiSelect Listbox'? Or do you mean Table?

Comment: Wayne, I appologise for being so cryptic, as you might understand these things are difficult to articulate. I need the selected values in the multi value listbox to be added to a table. Later I'd like repopulate these values based on the information previously added into the table. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: From looking at your code and description, I think I have an idea, but not sure. Seems you have a listbox containing dates and possibly other fields. A user selects any number of dates in the listbox and clicks a button to add 'Date' and 'list index' to the 'tblContacts' table. When you say 'repopulate', I don't know what you mean... Repopulate into the listbox? they should already be there? into another recordset?